# Can I get a `Traversal` to items stored in branches using `Control.Lens.Plated`?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, haskell-lens

I can easily get a `Traversal` to items stored in leaves:

```
data Tree a = Br (Tree a) (Tree a) | Lf a
    deriving (Data)

instance Plated (Tree a) where

makePrisms ''Tree

leaves :: Traversal' (Tree a) a
leaves = deep _Lf
```

But `deep` can't keep going if I take something out of a branch. The best I can seem to achieve with data in branches is a `Fold`:

```
data Tree a = Br a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Lf
    deriving (Data)

instance Plated (Tree a) where

makePrisms ''Tree

branchData :: Fold (Tree a) a
branchData = cosmos._Br._1
```

It is obviously possible to manually construct a `Traversal` because this `Tree` can be made `Traversable`:

```
instance Traversable Tree where
    sequenceA Lf = pure Lf
    sequenceA (Br x l r) = Br <$> x <*> sequenceA l <*> sequenceA r
```

Can `Plated` do it for us automatically somehow?

Comment: If you just want `traverse`, you could enable `-XDeriveTraversable` and have GHC derive the traversable instance for you.

Comment: @Zeta this was just an example, but the datatype I'm actually using is monomorphic, and there are different branches with different types of data in them. I asked the question more out of curiosity (and perhaps for future utility) to be honest: it obviously makes more sense in my current situation just to write the traversal manually in a few minutes rather than wait days for someone to answer my Stack Overflow question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to do using `Plated`, but it is trivial to do using `template` from [`Data.Data.Lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Data-Data-Lens.html):

```
branchData :: Data a => Traversal' (Tree a) a
branchData = template
```

Template finds all elements of a type that can be accessed without going through the same type.

---

The closest thing to a traversal that I can get from `Plated` (except for the `cosmos` fold you mentioned) is `transformM :: (Monad m, Plated a) => LensLike' m a a`. It can be used as a `Setter` and can do some other stuff.

The reason that transformM needs a Monad (instead of an Applicative that would be required for a traversal) is that we need to update the children before updating the node, which means that ordering is needed. It is impossible to make a traversal that points at both a node and a child of that node.